# SQL Query displaying duplicate results suddenly

Tags: mysql, sql

I am stumped after a day of troubleshooting. This MySQL query has been running successfully for a month and all of the sudden I am receiving duplicate results which is fouling up the entire management program it is relevant to.

My troubleshooting included searching the database for duplicate entries and none existed. For example, I used the search command in phpMyAdmin to display the entries where entry_id = 45 and field_id = 65. The result of the search displayed only one result which is correct. As of yesterday the below query displays the same result twice.

Query:

```
    SELECT f.id, f.title, f.type, f.name, v.id AS f_id, v.field_value
    FROM jos_directory_enf AS v
    LEFT JOIN jos_directory_field AS f ON f.id = v.field_id
    WHERE v.entry_id = 45 AND v.field_id = 65
```

Comment: Are all `f.id`'s you're pulling from the database identical? Is the duplicate rows entirely identical? You said you tried in phpMyAdmin - what happens if you perform the query directly from phpMyAdmin?

Comment: I have found the error. The fields in the table jos_directory_field have been duplicated (as to how they were duplicated, I have no clue). If anyone knows an easy way to remove duplicates using phpmyadmin please let me know. Thank you for your assistance.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to see if your joining tables have any duplicates in them that will result in more results to your main query.

Comment: Sure enough the fields in the table jos_directory_field were somehow duplicated in the database. Thank you!

Comment: Is there an easy way using phpmyadmin to delete duplicate entries in a database?

Comment: @user830381: Be sure to "accept" the correct answer by clicking the checkbox under the answer's vote count (also upvote it).  Second, do not ask a second question in a comment.  Post a new question with all the necessary information.

Answer (score 0):

It is difficult to answer your question without knowing details about your schema and the duplicated result. I guess your data was updated since the time where no duplicated were presented.
Look if v.id and v.field_value contain NULL values more than once for the same v.field_id or there rows with the same values for the columns, which you project in one of the two tables. Look if f.id or v.field_id have the same values in different rows.